# Tabula-Py: Reading entry incorrectly as NaN

Tags: python, tabula-py

I have some PDFs for a document of a specific format (called a CCSL), and it marks time in terms of "footage" (of film), like "12+45". I'm trying to use Tabula to read the PDF, but it interprets that as "NaN". My invocation for Tabula is:

```
import tabula

# Read pdf into list of DataFrame
dfs = tabula.read_pdf("/Path_to/A_CCSL_File.pdf", pages='all', pandas_options={'dtype': str})
```

But I still get this result. How else should I be invoking this?